# Is my proof of showing a helicoid and catenoid are isometric, correct?

Tags: differential-geometry

This is the question I have:

Let $S$ denote the surface of revolution $$(x,y,z)=(\cos\theta \cosh v, \sin \theta \cosh v, v)$$
 $0 < \theta < 2 \pi$ and   $-\infty < v <\infty$

and $S'$ the surface $$(x',y',z')=(u \cos \phi, u \sin \phi, \phi)$$

$0 < \phi < 2\pi$ and $ -\infty < u < \infty$

Let $f$ be the mapping which takes the point $(x,y,z)$ on $S$ to the point $(x',y',z')$ on $S'$ where $\theta =\phi$ and $u=\sinh v$.

Show that $f$ is an isometry from $S$ onto $S'$

This is my proof.

I reparametrise the helicoid as $$S'=(\sinh v \cos \theta, \sinh v \sin \theta ,\theta )$$

I then find the first fundamental forms of the reparametrized helicoid and the first fundamental forms of the  catenoid and show that they are the same.

> Is the outline of the proof correct?
>
> Have I re-parametrized the helicoid correctly?
>
> Do I need to reparametrise the catenoid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not shown that they share the same first fundamental form coefficients in your brief outline. You have correctly given the result.

EDIT1:

This is quite standard and can be found in several DG text books, and other sites. including code.

[Finding surface of revolution isometric to helicoid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1294073/finding-surface-of-revolution-isometric-to-helicoid)

http://xahlee.info/surface/helicoid-catenoid/helicoid-catenoid.html

Comment: This was a brief outline of the proof, But is the general outline of the proof correct? Do we not need to parametrise the catenoid?

Comment: You already parametrised catenoid in first line!  Hope you understand what you are doing.

Comment: Lets say I am now working out the first fundamental form and I calculate $E=\langle S'_\theta , S'_\theta \rangle$. I then get $\sinh^2 v \cos^2 \theta + \sinh^2 v \sin^2 \theta+ \theta^2$ which becomes just $\sinh^2 v + \theta^2$. Is this correct?

Comment: Ok,is it done?  what about $F$ and $ G?$

Comment: Before I work out the rest I want to check something, does $S'_\theta =(-\sinh v\ sin \theta, \sinh v \cos \theta, 1)$ and does $S'_v = (\cosh v \cos \theta, \cosh v \sin \theta, \theta)$?   So if these are correct then $F=\theta$?

Comment: Is $G=\cosh^2 v$?

Comment: is my working in the last two comments correct?

Answer (score 1):

This is good. You should find that the first fundamental form for both $S$ and $S^{\prime}$ are the same which is equivalent to being locally isometric and are equal to:
$$ds^2 = \cosh^{2}(v)\left(dv^2 + d\theta^2\right)$$